# Pattern matching java.lang.Long

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, scala-java-interop

I'm confused with scala pattern matching behaviour, see code below:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong

object LongPatternMatching {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    useJavaLong
    useScalaLong
    useComplexJavaLong
  }

  def useScalaLong: Unit = {
    val aLong: Long = Long.MaxValue
    aLong match {
      case v if v == Long.MinValue => println("min")
      case v if v == Long.MaxValue => println("max")
    }
  }

  def useJavaLong: Unit = {
    val aLong: java.lang.Long = java.lang.Long.MAX_VALUE
    aLong match {
      case v if v == java.lang.Long.MIN_VALUE => println("min")
      case v if v == java.lang.Long.MAX_VALUE => println("max")
    }

  }

  def useComplexJavaLong: Unit = {
    val counter: AtomicLong = new AtomicLong(0)
    counter.incrementAndGet() match {
      case count if count % 1000 == 0 => println(count)
    }
  }
}
```

First two functions are ok, but third(useComplexJavaLong) throws scala.MatchError: 1 (of class java.lang.Long)

Answer (score 3):

`useComplexJavaLong` only matches a single case where the remainder of the modolu operation is 0. What happens if the remainder isn't equal to 0? You get a `MatchError` since there is no case which handles that. In the case of your example, `1 % 1000` is equal to 1, not 0, and thus the pattern match blows up. You'll need an additional case:

```
def useComplexJavaLong: Unit = {
  val counter: AtomicLong = new AtomicLong(0)
  counter.incrementAndGet() match {
    case count if count % 1000 == 0 => println(count)
    case count => println(s"Remainder equals: ${count % 1000}")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the pattern matching in the method `useCompleJavaLong` is not complete. You can change it to

```
def useComplexJavaLong: Unit = {
    val counter: AtomicLong = new AtomicLong(0)
    counter.incrementAndGet() match {
      case count if count % 1000 == 0 => println(count)
      case other => println(other)
    }
  }
```